# Pass data to vue instance to all components vuejs rails

Tags: vue.js

I have this `Vue` instance as

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if(document.getElementById("app")){
    const node = document.getElementById('app');
    const props = JSON.parse(node.getAttribute('current_user'));

    const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      router,
      template: '<App />',
      components: { App }
    }).$mount('#app');
  }
 });
```

The data is in `const props` which contains user details such as email and password, it's in JSON form.

I have another component registered as

```
import CurrentUser from "../components/shared/CurrentUser";
Vue.component("v-current-user", CurrentUser);
```

And its been called in header. such as

```
<template>
  <header class="app-header navbar">
    <button class="navbar-toggler sidebar-toggler d-lg-none mr-auto" type="button" data-toggle="sidebar-show">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img class="navbar-brand-full" src="/images/evercam-logo-2.png" alt="Evercam Logo">
      <img class="navbar-brand-minimized" src="/images/Favicon-300.png" width="30" height="30" alt="Evercam Logo">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler sidebar-toggler d-md-down-none" type="button" data-toggle="sidebar-lg-show">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <v-current-user />
  </header>
</template>
```

All I want to do is to pass this props in such a way that any child component will receive it as well as I can send it to `<v-current-user />` and can get the values in that component where I am using this current user

```
<template>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        <v-gravatar email="junaid@evercam.io" class="img-avatar" :size="40" />
      </a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/users/sign_out">
          <i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Logout
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

in `<v-gravatar>` for email.
Sorry fo ambiguous questions I am a total newbie to Vuejs right now

Comment: You probably want a global store. A convenient place to put global data is in [`$root`](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Root-Instance) if you don't want to add [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/)

Comment: To add to @RoyJ 's comment, a more beginner friendly alternative to vuex is vue-stash https://github.com/cklmercer/vue-stash

Comment: as @RoyJ mentioned, `$root` is the most beginner friendly thing to do

Comment: for this to work use props as the data attribute when creating your root vue component.

Comment: anyone, please answer with an example?